# Let $B =$ {$(x,y) ∈\mathbb{R^2} : x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1$} and $D =$ {$(x,y) ∈\mathbb{R^2} : x^2 + y^2 < 1$}. Pick out the true statements.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

**[NBHM_2009_PhD Screening Test_Topology]**

> Let $B =\{(x,y) \in\mathbb{R^2} : x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ and $D =\{(x,y)
>  \in\mathbb{R^2} : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$. Pick out the true statements.
>
> (a) Given a continuous function $g : B \to\mathbb{R}$, there always
>   exists a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $f = g$ on $B$.
>
> (b) Given a continuous function $g : D \to\mathbb R$, there always
>   exists a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb R $such that
>   $f = g$ on $D$.
>
> (c) There exists a continous function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 →\mathbb R$
>   such that $f ≡ 1$ on the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2 = 3/2\}$
>   and $f ≡ 0$ on the set $B\cup \{(x,y) \in\mathbb {R}^2 : x^2+y^2 ≥ 2\}$.

I know $B$ is compact and $D$ is open. I know the fact that continuous image of a compact set is compact. I haven't study any extension theorem in topology. How do I solve the question? Please help me.

Comment: Robert 's answer is very to the point. I just want to say that, whenever u have a proper open set in domain then u can have a continuous function which goes to infinity at some of its boundary point. Hence that function cannot extend to Rn. That is not the case for a closed set. That is the difference between (a) and (b). Best of luck for NBHM

Comment: @SantanuDebnath Thank You, I have study the theories from different text book. Now, I am solving past year question papers. Can you give a suggestion? What extra things shall I do? Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. As regards (a) let $f=g$ in $B$ and define $f$ for $(x,y)\not \in B$ as
$$f(x,y)=g\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right).$$
Is $f$ a continuous map in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

For $(b)$ consider the function in $g:D\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+y^2}.$$

For $(c)$, is there a continuous function $h:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$h(3/2)=1 \quad\text{and}\quad h(x)=0\; \forall x\in [0,1]\cup [2,+\infty)?$$

Comment: (a) $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. Right? finding the limit through y=mx. it has different limit. Am I right?.

Comment: No, $f=g$ in $B$ and OUTSIDE is given by the definition I gave.

Comment: Thank you very much for (a). Let me think others.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan Fine. Let me know if you have further doubts.

Comment: sorry, I had the network problem yesterday. Thank you. I have gone through the solution.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I"m glad it helps.

Comment: Where is the problem, if I am defining a function  $f=g, $ in $D$ and define $f(x,y)=g(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}) $ in $D^c$

Comment: Try with $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$ which is continuous in $D$. Is the extension $f$ defined at $(1,0)$? Note that $g$ is unbounded in $D$ and the continuous extension $f$ should be bounded in the closure of $D$.